# PHP set the checkbox to be checked if data in Array 1 equal Array 2

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I have array that's retrieved from mysql.

Array `item_category` is an Array that shows all the categories.

Array `selected_category` is an array that shows the selected categories.

```
$item_category[32]="western food";  
$item_category[33]="chinese food";  
$item_category[34]="mix food";     
$item_category[35]="japanese food"; 
$item_category[36]="korean food";   
$item_category[37]="italian food";  

$selected_category[32]="western food"; 
$selected_category[33]="chinese food";  
$selected_category[34]="mix food";    

foreach ($item_category as $key => $value) {

    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[] "value="'.$key.'"> '.$value.'<br>';

}
```

[image]

1. use foreach loop to display out all the categories
2. check the checkbox in Array `$selected_category`.

So my question is how to check the checkbox just like the screenshot since they have the same "`Key`" in these 2 Arrays? I try something with the following but it doesn't work as what I expected.

```
$checked = true ? "checked" : "";
echo '<input type="checkbox" ' . $checked . ' name="check_list[] "value="'.$key.'"> '.$value.'<br>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if `$key` of `$item_category` presents in `$selected_category`. This can be done with `isset` function:

```
foreach ($item_category as $key => $value) {
    // check if `$key` set in `$selected_category` 
    $checked = isset($selected_category[$key])? 'checked' : '';

    echo '<input type="checkbox" ' . $checked .' name="check_list[] "value="'.$key.'"> '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$item_category[32]="western food";  
$item_category[33]="chinese food";  
$item_category[34]="mix food";     
$item_category[35]="japanese food"; 
$item_category[36]="korean food";   
$item_category[37]="italian food";  

$selected_category[32]="western food"; 
$selected_category[33]="chinese food";  
$selected_category[34]="mix food";    

foreach ($item_category as $key => $value)
{

    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[] "value="' . $key . '" ' . ((in_array($value), $selected_category) ? 'checked="checked"' : '') . '>    '.$value.'<br>';

}
```

[in_array() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) returns true if one specified value is present in one specified array

Answer (score 1):

Try below code it's works for you.

```
<?php
$item_category[32]="western food";  
$item_category[33]="chinese food";  
$item_category[34]="mix food";     
$item_category[35]="japanese food"; 
$item_category[36]="korean food";   
$item_category[37]="italian food";  

$selected_category[32]="western food"; 
$selected_category[33]="chinese food";  
$selected_category[34]="mix food";    

foreach ($item_category as $key => $value) {
      echo '<input type="checkbox" '.(isset($selected_category[$key])? 'checked' : '').' name="check_list[] "value="'.$key.'"> '.$value.'<br>';

}
```